# Size the Tableau Heat Map Logarithmically

Tags: heatmap, tableau-api, logarithm

I just realized you can plot x by y using logarithmic scale, i.e, x is time, and y is logarithmic scale

[image]

How do I adjust size of Heat Map to have logarithmic scale. Here is a heat map. Size is based on number of records

Note how 1 record and 600 records have same size

[image]

Here is size legend ----- how to fix?

[image]

## Logs

Before, most boxes were same size, with few exceptions

[image]

When I create calculated field to get log and convert to distrete, i.e.

[image]

I move it to size shelf.

All boxes are same size .... please advise

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply plot Log(Sum([Number of Records])) or Ln(Sum([Number of Records])).

To make it even easier to distinguish, you could make a discrete field by:

1. Creating a calculated field log_recs = Log(Sum([Number of Records]))
2. Creating a bin field based on log_recs with a bin size of 1

(or even simpler, skipping step 2 by wrapping the Log() call with a Floor() or Int() call) Be sure to set the field to be discrete in this case.

Then if you put your log_recs_bin field on the size shelf, you should get 4 or 5 discrete sizes, one for each order of magnitude.

**Edited** to call Sum() prior to calling Log()

Comment: I'm trying this out

Comment: How to make variable dependent on other fields? In this case, Number of Records depends on variable, A, B, and C. A1, B1 and C1 has 10000 records wherewas A2, B1, C3 has 10 records. Please clarify

Comment: Put whatever dimensions you want to use to partition your data on a shelf, say row or column

Comment: I keep trying, boxes are same, small size. Original question has been updated. Please advise.

Comment: Use floor or Int, not float. Then make the field DISCRETE. Using area for a 1 dimensional number is not always the best for user perception, but could be effective if you just a few values. You can also edit the size legend to adjust the presentation

Comment: Once you get the field returning a small number of discrete values, you could try encoding the value as a color instead of a size to aid perception. Maybe with darker hues for larger Values